# Java Applet and Print

Tags: java, swing, applet

From my webpage i am calling applet that having some credential information and try to print the applet content. But i need to invisible the applet information. The paper coming as a blank if suppose the i am trying to invisible editorpane or Jframe.

```
    //Print function

        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2d.translate(pageFormat.getImageableX(), pageFormat
                .getImageableY());
        disableDoubleBuffering(componentToBePrinted);
        componentToBePrinted.paint(g2d);
        enableDoubleBuffering(componentToBePrinted);
        return (PAGE_EXISTS);

   // applet    

    jbInit();  
    this.accessParamEditorPane.setEditable(false);
    Font f = new Font("Arial", 1, 9);
    this.accessParamEditorPane.setFont(f);
    this.accessParamEditorPane.setText(Body);
    //this.setVisible(false);
    //accessParamEditorPane.setVisible(false);
    new PrintModule(this);
    dispose();
    setFocusableWindowState(false);
```

Comment: Don't use `paint`, use `print` or `printAll`...You won't need to disable double buffering, as this is what these methods do, also, you may need to ensure that the component being printed actually has been size properly

Comment: I tried with printAll function..but i couldn't acheived..and also checked the component size..

Comment: I've just done a little stand alone example and it works fine for me.  Maybe you should consider providing a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Answer (score 1):

You can try to create another `JEditorPane` instance (visible one). Copy size of the original one, set the same `EditorKit` and set document obtained from the original one.

Then `printAll()` the new instance.